# a mile run for time

Tags: meaning, usage

For this:

> A Raider meet is designed to test the physical, mental and teamwork capabilities of its competitors, who work individually and in teams of eight. It includes a battery of physical fitness tests including push-ups, sit-ups and a mile run **for time**.
>
> —Dan McFarland, [*The Free Lance-Star*](http://www.freelancestar.com/2013-10-13/articles/20123/teams-tough-it-out-for-regional-honors/)

Does it mean the run was done to help pass time?  Because:

> a mile run ***for fun***

would probably mean it was done to obtain amusement.

Comment: It means that the competitors are attempting to run the mile in the shortest time they can.

Comment: @StoneyB  Would this "a mile run for ***shortest*** time" be better?

Comment: No, it's a technical term. People who run a lot distinguish between running "for time" and "for distance".

Comment: @StoneyB So, an average layman would easily misunderstand "*a mile run for time*"?

Comment: No, a **lot** of people run, and the rest of us have to listen to them talk about it! But a "mile run for time" is an odd thing to see without context. I suppose in this case it means a mile run against the clock as opposed to a 'race', with all the competitors starting at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand *running for fun* or *a mile run for fun*, you can understand this *a mile run **for time*** the same way. In short, this *for* is used for stating the purpose of the action.

I agree with StoneyB in his comment, *for time* in this context means aiming *for the best time* or *for the shortest time* the athlete can do in the given activity, which is running in this case. This *for time* is in contrast with another kind of running, which is *running for distance*.

As someone who loves water sports, I'd like to quote this passage from a book I found on Google Books. It has a similar example usage: *a 20-minute swim **for distance***:

> [...] To find the category most appropriate for you, you will take a test.
>   
>   The test is a 20-minute swim **for distance**. That is, you will see how far you can swim in 20 minutes. The distance you swim in the 20-minute time period will determine which level you will choose.
>   <sub>--[Swimming Workouts for Fitness and Training, by Richard Michaels](http://books.google.com/books?id=LuQGAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA30)</sub>
>   <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>